# 3D walls are blended/transparent

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

i'm trying to learn some 3D in XNA, and i used a .pdf called: 
`XNA 4 3D Game Development By Example For Beginners`, and in that .pdf it shows you how to create a game called "Cube Chaser", which you basically learn how to generate a maze, create a tiled floor, walls, First Person Camera, and also how to collect an object to finish the game.

So for the moment i have a fully working FPS-Camera + Movement(no collision though) and i also have a maze generator, now my problem is that when the maze generates, it creates walls(like it should..xD) but the walls are almost transparent. They have their color(red & orange) but every other wall in the maze is visible, i can see every wall in the map, so it's like if the wall would be transparent... It's hard to explain, so here's a picture of it:
http://tinypic.com/r/332mi3p/5

This is my *Draw* method for the Maze.cs:

```
public void Draw(Camera camera, BasicEffect basicEffect)
    {
        basicEffect.VertexColorEnabled = true;
        basicEffect.World = Matrix.Identity;
        basicEffect.View = camera.View;
        basicEffect.Projection = camera.projection;

        foreach(EffectPass pass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();
            device.SetVertexBuffer(floorBuffer);
            device.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, floorBuffer.VertexCount / 3);

            device.SetVertexBuffer(wallBuffer);
            device.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, wallBuffer.VertexCount / 3);
        }
    }
```

(wallBuffer = walls, floorBuffer = floor..ehh xD)

Comment: I think the **z-buffer is disabled** and the red colors are the front of the polygon, the yellow are the backsides?

Comment: Ye, red represents one side, yellow another side. What's a z-buffer?
sorry if it's a nooby question.. :/

Comment: A Z-Buffer is a depth buffer, it will prevent the rasterizer from rendering pixels. (like the walls behind the first wall). You should google on Z-buffer, Depthbuffer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976071.aspx) Also you might wanna look to Backface culling, (preventing rendering the backsides of polygons.

Comment: I searched around on google for Z-Buffer and how to enable it and stuff, but i didn't make any progress, i tried to experiment more with my code, but still it's the same :/ Any ideas...?

Comment: Sorry, i did some direct3d/wpf viewport3d, never digged into xna. There are some forums, maybee they can help. Start here: http://www.gamedev.net/

Comment: I've been looking though the forums for a while, but it was almost only in DirectX, and non of em' owrked :/
Is there any solution..?